# How to use the SDK without the dependency on a main video

Tags: google-ima

I am trying to put an ad without the need to put a video,
I tried to remove the video in the function and in the html view, but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

**Code**

```
adsManager.init(640, 360, google.ima.ViewMode.NORMAL);
```